# SQL calculate share of grouped variables to total count

Tags: sql, impala

Its probably very easy, bot somehow I cannot get the desired result:

My data looks like this: I have a large table with items sold. Each item has a category assigned (here A-D) and country. I would like to calculate how many items were sold in Europe, in each category, and what is the share of this particular category to total sales

my data looks like this:

| country | item_id | item_cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | 1 | A |
| Europe | 2 | A |
| Europe | 3 | B |
| Europe | 4 | B |
| Europe | 5 | C |
| Europe | 6 | C |
| Europe | 7 | C |
| USA | 8 | D |
| USA | 9 | D |
| USA | 10 | D |

my desired output like this:

| country | item_cat | cat_sales | total_sales | share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | A | 2 | 7 | 0.29 |
| Europe | B | 2 | 7 | 0.29 |
| Europe | C | 3 | 7 | 0.43 |

what I tried is:

```
SELECT 
   country, 
   item_cat, 
   count(*) as cat_sales,
   count(*) OVER () as total_sales,
   cat_sales / total_sales as share
FROM data
where country='Europe'
group by item_cat
```

but SQL tells me I cannot group and use windowing in one request.
How could i solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways, one would be to pre-count the total sales in a CTE and then select from it for the remaining aggregate.

I don't use impala however in standard SQL this should work

```
with tot as (
    select *, 
      Count(*) over(partition by country) * 1.0 as total_sales
    from t
)
select country, item_cat, 
    Count(*) as cat_sales, 
    total_sales,
    Round(Count(*) / total_sales, 2) as Share
from tot
where country='europe'
group by country, item_cat, total_sales
```

Comment: Thank you! One little question though: should I add the filter `where country='europe'` within the `with (...)` statement as well,  in order to reduce the load and increase the speed of execution, if it pre-calculates everything, or only at the end of the statement as in your example?

Comment: Yes you can do that, in which case you won't need the partition